# message between chrome extension to already running C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, process

I'm writing C# application and Chrome extension that should send message to each others

the problem that the Chrome extension have to run the native application to be start send message to it and it don't send any message if the application is already running
but the user have to open the C# application before the extension.
so any solution/trick for that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make an application that will run as a proxy to the messages to your running .net app.